# How to replace XFCE window manager with awesome

Tags: debian, xfce, awesome

How can I replace XFCE4 window manager with awesome?

I tried to place the following content to the `~/.xinitrc` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec awesome
```

I also tried to do [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/281135) stuff:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command -t string -s "awesome" -a
```

And it doesn't work. Of course I already installed awesome via

```
sudo apt-get install awesome
```

Comment: Don't forget to clear your session! After running that command, xfwm4 will still be started because it was running in your last session. Clearing your session will prevent that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from https://awesomewm.org/wiki/Awesome_and_Xfce4

1. Go to: `Settings -> Session and Startup -> Current Session`
2. And change `Restart Style` of xfwm4 to `Never`
3. Then go to `Application Autostart` and add `awesome`

It should work after restarting xfce

Answer (score 6):

On the fly, you can type :

```
killall xfwm4 && awesome &
```

To exchange permanently, you can edit `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml` and replace `xfwm4` with `awesome`.

Comment: Many window managers also have a `--replace` option, like so: `awesome --replace&`, called from a shell or startup option.  However, I do not have `awesome` so I cannot test it.

Comment: @Ned64 awesomewm does not currently have the `--replace` flag (as of v3.5.9)

Comment: But it seems to be present in Awesome 4.2.